# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql netbeans, *.jar include in library

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

I can perform the connection in worbanch, but with the same username and password can not connect through the application in the mysql database. I checked the syntax apparently seems to be correct. I would like to help to solve this problem as the .jar is already in the library folder of Java SE project.

print screen:

[Screen 1](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6B6A9C455A7657FF!139986&authkey=!AE5066_LFf8tMP4&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng)

[screen 2](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6B6A9C455A7657FF!139987&authkey=!AC21AlYVvapa2UU&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng)

**ERROR CONSOLE: `No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/sakila`**

Comment: use mysql inbuld driver.

Comment: screens not loading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just simply add the library to your project library. Right click in Library on the Project you use

[image]

Then choose MySQL JDBC Driver

[image]

Then Click Add Library.So now we can connect to MySQL database

Resource :[Java MySQL JDBC Tutorial using NetBeans (Part 1)](https://ferdidolot.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/java-mysql-jdbc-tutorial-using-netbeans-part-1/)

Comment: Thank You So Much!